# Run JavaScript editor for OpenStreetMap

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap

> > How to run iD editor (JavaScript editor for OpenStreetMap) in windows environment

Comment: I downloaded zip file from the GitHub I am not getting how to run this.

Comment: Did you follow the [installation instructions](https://github.com/openstreetmap/iD#installation)? And what exactly is the reason for running it locally?

Comment: I want to know how they are drawing points,  areas etc. directly on maps. I want to run this and want to debug to develop some knowledge on d3 and OSM.

Comment: If you want to learn about the techniques used in the iD editor project the following blog is an excellent resource: https://www.mapbox.com/osmdev/